# Gulp: Splitting Files Into Separate Locations

Tags: coffeescript, gulp

I'd like to separate my **JavaScript** files from my **Coffee-Script** files!

This is my **current** file structure:

```
engine
  world
    behaviour.coffee
    behaviour.js
  character
    behaviour.coffee
    behaviour.js
  engine.coffee
  engine.js
```

This is the structure I would **prefer**:

```
src
  engine
    world
      behaviour.coffee
    character
      behaviour.coffee
    engine.coffee
```

and:

```
dest
  engine
    world
      behaviour.js
    character
      behaviour.js
    engine.js
```

my actual **gulp file** looks like this:

```
gulp = require 'gulp'
coffee = require 'gulp-coffee'

gulp.task 'all-coffee-files', ->
  gulp.src './**/*.coffee'
  .pipe coffee()
  .pipe gulp.dest (file) ->
    file.base

gulp.task 'watch', ->
  gulp.watch './**/*.coffee', ['all-coffee-files']
```

What edits do I have to make in order to achieve this **splitting**?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really familiar with coffescript syntax, but the following should work:

```
gulp = require 'gulp'
coffee = require 'gulp-coffee'

gulp.task 'all-coffee-files', ->
  gulp.src './src/**/*.coffee'
  .pipe coffee()
  .pipe gulp.dest('./dest/')

gulp.task 'watch', ->
  gulp.watch './src/**/*.coffee', ['all-coffee-files']
```

This sources everything in `./src/` and places the resulting `.js` files  in `./dest/`, while keeping the directory structure intact.

Comment: Yes, thank you!! I didn't know that `gulp.dest './dest/'` keeps the directory "intact" :D.